# Maximally symmetric discrete subsets of the sphere

Tags: group-theory, geometry

Let $d\geq 1$ and $\mathbb{S}^{d}=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{d+1}:|x|=1\}$.

For $X\subset\mathbb{S}^{d}$, $|X|<\infty$, let $T(X)=\{A\in\mathbb{R}^{(d+1)\times (d+1)} : A\in \text{SO}(d+1), A(X)=X\}$.

What is known about

$f_d(n):=\max_{X\subset \mathbb{S}^{d}, |X|=n}|T(X)|$?

I have

- $f_{d-1}(n)\leq f_d(n)\leq n!$
- $f_{d}(d+2)=(d+2)!/2$ and $f_{d+1}(d+2)=(d+2)!$ (both attained by simplex with $d+2$ vertices. In the second case the orientation restriction falls away)

I wonder if maximizers of $f_d(n)$ for large $n$ are distributed quasi-uniformly in some sense (as are the vertices of a simplex), which is why I am interested in the question.

Comment: This seems like a pretty broad question.  An $n$-simplex will attain symmetry $S_{n+1}$ if I understand what you mean by "rigid transformation" as isometry of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.  Note the collision of notations for permutation group and sphere.

Comment: Yes, a simplex is what I consider maximally symmetric, and this shows $f_d(d+2)=(d+2)!/2$ (note the edited question, the division by 2 can be omitted if the orthogonal group is considered instead).